# Ror: Import of a ics file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icalendar

I added to my project the capability to import calendars (ics files). The code is something like this:

```
  events = ICS::Event.file(File.open(ics_temp_file))
  events.each do |event|
    if event.summary and event.started_on and event.description
      Event.create(:description => event.description == '\n' ? nil : event.description,
                   :organization_id => @organization.id,
                   :user_id => current_user.id,
                   :event_type => Event::OTHER,
                   :date_time => event.started_on,
                   :title => event.summary,
                   :active => true)
    else
      logger.warn("***Error*** Importing ics (bad event)")
    end
  end
```

As we can see, i'm using the gem ics. I researched a couple of months ago and it looked like the best option for paring ics files, that is extracting the events of a ics file.
This gem can extract events like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
something here
END:VEVENT.
```

The problem is the following; some users tried to import calendars (i don't know what tool they used to create the calendar) but the events are like this:

```
BEGIN:VFREEBUSY
something here
END:VFREEBUSY.
```

So the cuestion is, do you know a better alternative for parsing ics files? maybe something that can extract all kind of events and you can do something like
events.map(&:vevents) or events.map(&:vfreebusy). Do you have any ideas to handle this? Thank you!

edit: sorry, i forget to mention that the list of known attributes for this gem is this

```
    TRANSP
    DTEND
    UID
    DTSTAMP
    LOCATION
    DESCRIPTION
    URL
    STATUS
    SEQUENCE
    SUMMARY
    DTSTART
    CREATED
# For the alarm…
    # BEGIN:VALARM (ignored)
    X-WR-ALARMUID
    TRIGGER
    ATTACH
    ACTION
    # END:VALARM (ignored)
```

hence it is easy to see why this gem is not extracting all kinds of events.

Comment: Aehm ... I think there is a typo in your post ... or I haven't yet have enough coffee: "The problem here is that this gem can extract events like this:" and then "The problem is the following; some users tried to import calendars (i don't know what tool they used to create the calendar) but the events are like this:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try iCalendar: https://github.com/sdague/icalendar. It parses ics files and supports the type of events you mentioned: https://github.com/sdague/icalendar/blob/master/lib/icalendar/parser.rb#L139.